# a bug in erlang node after an error at another node

Tags: erlang, elixir

i created 2 erlang nodes in the same Windows machine with two cmd windows:'unclient@MYPC' and 'unserveur@MYPC' , the server code is very simple :

```
-module(serveur).
-export([start/0,recever/0,inverse/1]). 
%%%%
start() -> 
process_flag(trap_exit,true), 
Pid=spawn_link(serveur,recever,[]), 
register(ownServer, Pid). 
%%%%
recever() -> 
receive 
{From, X} ->From ! {ownServer,1/X} 
end. 
%%%%
inverse(X) -> 
ownServer!{self(), X}, 
receive 
{'EXIT',_, _} ->start(), 
                sorry;

{ownServer, Reply} ->Reply 
end.
```

so at the server node cmd i start this module

```
c(serveur). 
serveur:start().
```

and i tested this server :at the server node cmd i used :

```
apply(serveur,inverse,[2]).
```

and i received 0.5 and i tried too causing an error by using an atom in the place of a number :

```
apply(serveur,inverse,[a]).
```

and the shell shows the error and shows  'sorry' and the server returns to its work correctly by restarting his child automatically because it is a system process and he traps the exit of his child.

now at the client node i used the rpc call function to try the connection and all is fine, for example i try :

```
rpc:call('unserveur@MYPC' ,serveur,inverse,[2]).
```

and at the client node cmd i receive :0.5

now i use an atom to send it to the server for causing an error

```
rpc:call('unserveur@MYPC' ,serveur,inverse,[a]).
```

at the client cmd node :
i waited for the response from the server that should be 'sorry' but i didn't receive anything and there is no more the client prompt :

```
unclient@MYPC 1>
```

i can write but the shell does not execute my instructions anymore and there is not any prompt. 
at the server node :
 i see an error and then the server prompt returns normally

```
unserveur@MYPC 5>
```

i tried this at the server node prompt :

```
apply(serveur, inverse, [2]).
```

and i had an error, so i restart the server manually by calling the start() function at the server node cmd and after that the server returns to work normally. 
I tried self() on the server node cmd before and after the  client call and the pid is the same and this is logic because the main server process is a system process so my result that he didn't execute the code after receive {'EXIT',...}. 
why that happens ? i couldn't understand this bug so any one can explain to me please what that happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the `EXIT` message is sent to any process that is linked to the server process, which is not necessarily the same process that sent the message.

It works when you run it in the shell, since the shell process gets linked to the server process, and the shell process is also the one that calls the `inverse` function.  However, when you make an RPC call, the `inverse` function is called from a different process.

Try making the RPC call from the client, and then running `flush().` in the shell of the server node, and you should see the `EXIT` message.

Comment: we have three processes :1-the client shell process 2-the server shell process 3-the server child process who run recever. the client shell process is not linked to any process, he send the call to the server shell process who execute apply(serveur, inverse, [a]), when the server child process die, his father is interested because he is linked to it but the client shell process is not interested

Comment: ok we consider that when i did the rpc call the function is called from the shell client process like you said, i tried calling the start()function from the client cmd node, so now the client process is the caller of this function and he will be the father linked process to the server process alright ? when i did the rpc call to the inverse function with an atom i had the same result :no 'sorry' and the prompt desapear and no restarting to the server process how do you can explain that ?

Comment: please answer me legoscia , i add ```io:format("~p~n", [self()]) ``` to the head of the inverse function and i had a different Pid for every rpc : call why ?

Comment: The RPC server usually spawns a new process for every call - but note that [the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rpc.html#call-5) says "You cannot make **any** assumptions about the process that will perform the `apply()`. It may be the calling process itself, an rpc server, another server, or a freshly spawned process."

Comment: thank you legoscia i readed the source code of the rpc call and i traced the call and understanding everything i had another post you can see how i resolved this probelm

Comment: i had just a last thing legoscia i see that rpc:call is a bit complicated function and i can't make all rex processes to be system processes because this affect the performance of the program so how i can monitor the failed calls ? is the rpc:call bad for performance of programs ?